# Profile picture in registration form WordPress

Tags: user-registration

I have custom built registration form and i want an option were in a user can upload and display his/her image as a profile picture. Now  once a user is registered and have uploaded the profile image then in that case if the user comment on a blog post on the same website then the same profile picture will be displayed. Can you give a script for the same.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to roll your own usermeta and integration with the WordPress Media library.

I recommend just directing the users to gravatar.com, where WP is fully integrated with, and use the same email they register to the site with to upload their photo there.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the code from this to start with...  It works pretty well...  I have found that the less than average internet user backs out of Gravatar...  If you require them to go to gravatar for registration, you will lose 90-95% of potential registrations.

http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-user-avatar/